# My Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 stops at this screen

Tags: ubuntu, startup, gnome

My Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 stops at this screen. Please Help.
[image]

Comment: off topic? try super user

Comment: There's an Ubuntu stack exchange too.

Comment: that would be better :thumbs_up:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with user manager. I am not certain if this is fixable. It is not a problem with gnome.

You will have to reinstall ubuntu to fix this or boot into advanced options for Ubuntu and open the recovery.